# Conditional label Woocommerce archive [unsolved]

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm building a webshop with Wordpress and Woocommerce. On the productoverview (archive) of a productcategories I want to show a label if the product has the category 'New'. The following code works on the product-single, but it won't show on the productcategory-page if I add the action in content-product.php.

I used the following code to show a label on the single product page and it works as it should.

```
function resign_article_is_new(){

    if ( is_product() && has_term( 'Nieuw', 'product_cat' ) ) {
        echo '<p class="new-lable">New</p>';
    }
}
add_action( 'resign_new_article', 'resign_article_is_new');
```

When I want to show the label on the productcategory overview I used this, but the label wouldn't appear.

```
do_action('resign_new_article');
```

Hope you can tell me what I'm doing wrong

Comment: `is_product()` is not true on product archives. You should just remove that condition. Since it's a custom action you don't need to worry about affecting other post types.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the Woo product loop, to output extra content on shop/archive pages (unless you use a custom template)

Try something like this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'conditional_label', 5 );
 
function conditional_label() {
   global $product;
   if (has_term( 'new', 'product_cat', $product->get_id())) {
        echo '<p class="new-lable">New</p>';
   }
}
```

Not tested, but should get you in the right direction.

Have a look at this [hook guide](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-archiveshopcat-page/), for a visualization on where you can add the text.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution seems not working. There is still nothing shown

Comment: Where did you add the code? Needs to go in functions.php

Comment: To keep things organised I use several functions.php (like woocommerce-functions.php etc) which I rever to in the main functions.php so I added the code in that file.

Answer (score 0):

After messing around with the code I found a solution to add a categorie label straight under the sales-tag on a product archive page.

```
//Tonen van Nieuw-label op archive page
function show_new_label(){

    //Check all the categories of taxonomy product_cat
    $argsTax = array('orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC', 'fields' => 'all');
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms(get_the_id(), 'product_cat', $argsTax);
    
    if(count($terms) > 0){
        foreach($terms as $term){
            $output .= $term->name; //name, slug, term_id, term_group, term_taxonomy_id, taxonomy, description, parent, count
        }
    };

    //Store all taxonomies in a variable
    $outputVar = $output;

    //Check if the right taxonomy is stored in the variable
    if(strpos($outputVar, 'New') !== false){
        echo '<p class="new-lable">New</p>';
    } else{
        
    }

}
//Attach the function to the 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item'-loop
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'show_new_label', 10 );
```

Maybe not the most clean code, but it works perfect